# Redirect link to new window from html?

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

I am having a html where i want to redirect to next page

```
<a href="www.facebook.com" target="_blank">www.facebbok.com</a>
```

It is redirecting to `localhost:9000/dashboard/www.facebook.com`

But i need to redirect only to www.facebook.com May i know how to do

Comment: try adding http://

Comment: Prepend your URL with `http://` or `https://`

Answer (score 1):

Use `<a href="https://www.facebook.com">` to get the redirect behaviour you want

```html
<a href="https//www.facebook.com" target="_blank">www.facebook.com</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

add `http://` or `https://` to your href. Without it, the link will automatically append your href with your base url.

e.g. `<a href="google.com">google</a>` will send you to `http://localhost/google.com` where as `<a href="http://google.com">google</a>` will redirect you to `http://google.com`